# Variations of Dijkstra's Algorithm for graphs with two weight properties

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I'm trying to find a heuristic for a problem that is mapped to a directed graph with say non-negative weight edges. However, each edge is associated with **two** weight properties as opposed to only one weight (e.g. say one is distance, and another one showing how good the road's 4G LTE coverage is!). Is there any specific variation of `dijkstra`, `Bellman Ford`, or any other algorithm that pursues this objective? Of course, a naive workaround is manually deriving a single weight property as a combination of all of them, but this does not look good.

Can it be generalized to cases with multiple properties?

Comment: Can you elaborate about what you're looking for specifically? What sort of balance between the weights are you trying to strike? For example, do you want a path with the lowest sum? The most beautiful of all the shortest paths? Something else? Without knowing this, I don't think anyone can provide a good answer.

Comment: Say 2nd property is how good the road's 4G LTE coverage is. So a basic desire would be not to choose a route with a total number of miles without coverage of less than a threshold. And more interestingly, `10 number of 0.1-mile` disconnection is better than a whole `continuous 1 mile` of disconnection! Assume I am talking over phone, and I don't want the delay exceed a defined `X` seconds. Anything is fine for me...just something that more sounds like a real-world scenario.

Comment: @TinaJasmin You may want to think about how to precisely pin down the property you're looking for. For example, can you write out a set of restrictions that the route needs to satisfy to be legal? Can you assign a "cost" to a route based on all the criteria? If you have to choose between multiple options, none of which are perfect, how would you decide which one to pick?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I need to first define those restrictions before deriving an algorithm.

Comment: @templatetypedef Asked the question here. You can help since you are already in the context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465235/modified-dijkstra-to-find-most-optimized-shortest-path-given-extra-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to optimize simultaneously two criteria: distance and attractiveness (and say path attractiveness is defined as the attractiveness of the most attractive edge, although you can think of different definitions). The following variation of Dijkstra can be shown to work, but I think it is mainly useful where one of the criteria takes a small number of values - say attractiveness is *1, ..., k* for some small fixed *k* (smaller *i* is better).

The [standard pseudocode for Dijsktra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue) uses a single priority queue. Instead use *k* priority queues. Priority queue *i* will correspond in Dijkstra's algorithm to the shortest path to a node *v ∈ V* with attractiveness *i*.

Start by initializing that each node is in each of the queues with distance *∞* (because, initially, the shortest path to *v* with attractiveness *i* is infinite).

In the main Dijkstra loop, where it says

```
 while Q is not empty
```

change it to

```
 while there is an i for which Q[i] is not empty
     Q = Q[i] for the lowest such i
```

and continue from there.

Note that when you update, you pop from queue `Q[i]`, and insert to `Q[j]` for *j ≥ i*.

It's possible to modify the proof of Dijkstra's relaxation property to show that this works.

Note that you will obtain up to *k |V|* results, as per node and attractiveness, you can have the shortest distance to the node with the given attractiveness.

**Example**

Taking an example from the comments:

> So basically if a path has a total no-coverage miles of >10, then we go for another path.

Here, e.g., assuming the miles are integers (or can be rounded to integers), we could create 11 queues: queue *i* corresponds to the shortest distance with *i* no-coverage miles, except for 10, which corresponds to 10-or-higher no-coverage-miles.

At some point of the algorithm, say all queues are empty below queue 3. We pop queue 3, and update the vertex's neighbors: this might update, e.g., some node in queue 4, if the distance from the popped node to the other node is 1.

As the algorithm runs, it outputs mappings of *(node, no-coverage-distance) → shortest distance*. Here, you could decide that you discard all mappings for which the second item in the pair is 10.

Comment: What you say is to keep k times more space every time. So actually we compute Dijkstra probably k times, store the results into k different queues, and request from each based on our need?!

Comment: One problem is how to compute attractiveness. Let's take this example and derive formulation for it: Say this attractiveness is how good the road's network coverage is, form level 1 to 5. So a basic desire would be not to choose a route with a total no-coverage miles of less than a threshold. So basically if a path has a total no-coverage miles of >10, then we go for another path. Can you apply your k-queue approach to this example?

Comment: And if we want to elaborate more, say 10 number of 0.1-mile no-coverage is better than a whole continuous 1 mile of no-coverage. So the problem is how to define this attractiveness? I just need some ideas.

Comment: @TinaJasmin "So basically if a path has a total no-coverage miles of >10, then we go for another path" - Added a detailed example for this case. Beyond that, I truly feel you should ask separate questions - this is too long and detailed for a single question.

Comment: I was discussing the question with a friend yesterday, and came into some partial interesting formulations, however, we guess it might be np-hard :-/ will ask it separately. It is very interesting and complicated question

Comment: Asked the question here. You can help since you are already in the context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465235/modified-dijkstra-to-find-most-optimized-shortest-path-given-extra-properties

Comment: Sure, I'll be happy to look at it.